# NotImplementedError in Google Cloud Dataflow and PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I encountered an error when I was testing Dataflow locally on my computer. I intended to use the streaming service from Dataflow and got a "NotImplementedError". The detail of the error is like this:
[image]

I thought it might be caused by some package versions. The following is the list of dependencies in the setup.py file.

```
'google-api-core==1.4.1',
'google-auth==1.5.1',
'google-cloud-core==0.28.1',
'google-cloud-storage==1.10.0',
'google-resumable-media==0.3.1',
'googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3',
'librosa==0.6.2',
'wave==0.0.2',
'scipy==1.1.0',
'google-api-python-client==1.7.4',
'oauth2client==4.1.2',
'resampy==0.2.1',
'keen==0.5.1',
'google-cloud-bigquery==1.5.0',
'apache-beam[gcp]==2.5.0',
'google-cloud-dataflow==2.5.0',
'six==1.10.0',
'google-cloud-logging==1.7.0'
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Looking here

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.py#L370

It seems that this isn't a configuration problem but rather a logic/usage puzzle.  I think the answer to the question is likely going to involve tracing back though the original path and see what step in the flow was being executed and ensuring that it is possible to do what is being asked.

Comment: Today I stumbled upon this issue when trying to run a dataflow using DirectRunner. It worked just fine last week. What I did is I created a fresh python environment and installed only 'apache-beam[gcp]==2.5.0' library and it works. So it looks it's some dependencies issue.